# How to simulate power sets in structural set theory (ETCS)?

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, set-theory

How to simulate power sets in structural set theory (ETCS)?

> (nlab) It turns out that one of the primary attributes of a structural set theory is that the elements of a set have no “internal” structure; they are only given structure by means of functions and relations. In particular, they are not themselves sets

Answer (score 2):

As you can see [here](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/ETCS) the axioms of ETCS implies that the *category of sets* is a [topos](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/topos).

If you take a look at one of the definitions in the link above you can easily see that a topos is a category that has [power-objects](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/power+object) which are basically the categorical generalization of power-sets you are looking for.

Take a look to the links for more details.

Comment: Prince Adam had a power object! And when he raised his Power Sword and called upon the power of Grayskull, HE HAD THE POWERRRRRR!!!! :-)